# Can Lean Six Sigma be implemented in a Service-Oriented Company?

Tags: lean, 6-sigma

In the past I've studied about implementing Lean Six Sigma methodologies, but the literature and the use cases were related to product-oriented environment. Can Lean Six Sigma methodologies be implemented in a service-oriented environment?

Comment: Welcome to PMSE! I've edited your question to prevent it from being closed as a search or link question. You can improve your question further by adding some context, and perhaps some references to the literature you're referencing.

Answer (score 3):

### Convergys reported successful Six Sigma implementation

Convergys is a customer care company with call centers in many countries. I happen to know that they implemented Six Sigma in their call centers (service-oriented environment) in India and reported major savings. [Here is a list of Lean Six Sigma success stories](http://www.goleansixsigma.com/lean-six-sigma-success-stories-in-the-high-technology-industry/), including the Convergys' one. You might want to check these out and see whether any of it gives you additional info for the service-oriented environment.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are asking whether Lean Six Sigma methodologies can be applied on services/non-physical products and services as service-oriented companies may have physical products and vice versa.

Surely some methodologies are more suitable for production, but you can also eliminate waste in service delivery and processes in general. Health care is one example where Six Sigma and Lean Six Sigma have been used extensively, often with success.

**Some examples on what waste that can be eliminated in services/processes**

- Waiting - Also immaterial processes may have prerequisites
- Over production & Over processing - services can also they be over delivered

Sources: Own experiences as a Lean Six Sigma Black Belt